# Is there a delay to include call function modification in a scheduled cron task?

Tags: cron, testing

I´m testing my cron task.
I´m not sure but it seems to be the effect of a previous code.
So, I´m wondering when you modify you call function and you run now your cron task (I´m using WP Control) and you load a page, the code applied is not the most recent code you upload.
It´s right or wrong ?
What happens excalty, call functions are cached ?

Comment: When you schedule an event, the function that is run is the function as it is when it is run, not when it was scheduled. There’s no caching of the function when the event is scheduled. Is that what you’re asking?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, yes, thank you. I wanted to confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens excalty, call functions are cached ?

**They do not get cached.**

When you schedule a cron job, it stores a record in the database to trigger a hook with certain parameters at a time/date. No code is cached.

So when that time comes, the code is loaded and run from the disk as it is at that time, not when it was scheduled.

For example, if I schedule a cron job for tomorrow that writes the word "hello" to a file, then immediately change the function to instead send an email, when the cron job runs an email is sent.